# Traffic of virtual machine capture in ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wireshark

I have ubuntu 12 running on my PC . On this Ubuntu, I have another linux distribution running on a virtual machine (virtual box).

When I launch a ping from ubuntu to the virtual machine, the ping work without problems.

When I try to capte the traffic with wireshark, the wireshark show only the traffic from the virtual machine to the ubuntu. the traffic from the ubuntu to the virtual machine is not displayed.

How to fix that? I want the wireshark show the traffic from both sides

Remarks

1) If I ping from the virtual machine to another equipment (not my PC) in the same network I will get the both traffic displayed in the wireshark

2) If I ping from the Ubuntu to another equipment (not a virtual machine in my PC) in the same network I will get the both traffic displayed in the wireshark

3) the problem is not related to wireshark because the problem is reproduced with the `tcpdump`

The network config of the virtual machine:

> **Mode:** bridge
>
> **Type:** PCNet-FastIII

Comment: Which virtual network mode are you using (NAT, bridged, etc.)?

Comment: Have you set promiscuous capture mode in wireshark?

Comment: @heavyd. it's bridge. I will update my question with the network config